# What is "Direct Penetration" from The Book of Five Rings book of Water?

Tags: sword, japanese, samurai

The translation of the book of Water of The Book of Five Rings at http://www.bookoffiverings.com/WaterBook.htm states:

> The spirit of Direct Penetration is handed down in the true Way of the Ni To Ichi School.
>   Teach your body strategy. You must practice well. This is transmitted orally.

It has been a few centuries since this was published - is this now recorded, has it been lost, or is there some unlikely school which still retains a legitimate oral tradition? If it has not been lost, what is the "spirit of Direct Penetration"?

Comment: I saw the title and came here expecting some puns, I'm a little bit disappointed.

Comment: @IEatBagels I laughed out loud on seeing the title, and that was enough for me.

Comment: @Hashim wow... I did not even realize that my title could be read... I'd wondered at IEatBagels' comment... Sigh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following [translations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GWEoL3xlMKQC) (by [Victor Harris](https://www.christies.com/features/Unique-among-swords-an-interview-with-Victor-Harris-on-the-Samurai-Aesthetic-5275-1.aspx) and [Thomas Cleary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fL__xCDDHusC)) instead translate the phrase as "Direct Communication":

> The spirit of "Direct Communication" is how the true Way of the Ni To Ichi school is received and handed down.

The [corresponding passage in Japanese](http://1.ariken.info/archives/146) (possibly modernized Japanese) is:

> わたしは、勝利に直結するあり方を、わが流派の道としてお伝えします。
>
> よく練習して、わが流派をきわめて下さい。
>
> 詳しくは口頭で伝えますね。

I don't speak Japanese, but Google Translate gives the following:

> I will tell you how to directly lead to victory as the way of our school.
> Practice often, please refrain from our school.
> For details, I will tell you verbally.

Looking at translations of individual words, and the context, I'd say that this is not a reference to some secret technique, or school of fighting, but a simple statement that he's talking straight, not producing flowery metaphor from which someone is supposed to figure it out for themselves.